# Run and interrupt threads after some time

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I want to run some amount of threads simultaneously and stop them all after some time. Is this correct? :

```
 object = new MyClass(numberThreads, time);
 object.start();

//wait in main thread
    try {
        object.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now in Class MyClass I have:

```
public void run() {

    SecondClass[] secObj= new SecondClass[numberThreads];

    //start all
    for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
        secObj[i] = new SecondClass();
        secObj[i].start();
    }

    try {
        //wait
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("end");
    }
        //Interrupt all
        for (int i = 0; i < par; i++) {
            secObj[i].interrupt();
        }
}
```

Sometimes after all the threads are interrupted it seems to be that some of them were not started, but if they all run for the same time everyone should have executed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, threads are scheduled by the thread scheduler. The thread scheduler decides when a specific thread gets CPU time. Saying that every thread needs the same time to finish. However you can influence the thread scheduler a bit by prioritizing threads over others (setPriority() method). You don't know in advance how long every thread needs to finish its work. Another thing is that if you are interrupting your thread with "interrupt()" you actually have to react to an interrupt. Usually you do this by catching the InterruptException and call "return;". Please post the code of SecondClass.

Comment: In SecondClass I have while(!Thread.interrupted()){
//do job
}

Answer (score 0):

```
object.join();
```

This code will wait in the main thread for the finish of the MyClass thread.

Then in the MyClass you have a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
    secObj[i] = new SecondClass();
    secObj[i].start();
}
```

This loop starts new threads of the SecondClass, quantity of threads = **numberThreads**.

Then:

```
//wait
Thread.sleep(time);
```

If time to sleep is too small - then MyClass may send interrupt even before some SecondClass threads may start.

But then you interrupt different number of threads "**par**", I don't see where you declare it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < par; i++) {
    secObj[i].interrupt();
}
```

So, you interrupt different number of threads. If you handle exception in SecondClass, then it still may be working after MyClass finish.

My example:

```
public class MyClass extends Thread {
private int numberThreads;
private int time;

static class SecondClass extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}

MyClass(int numberThreads, int time){
    this.numberThreads = numberThreads;
    this.time = time;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass object = new MyClass(6, 1000);
    object.start();
    //wait in main thread
    try {
        object.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread is finished");
}

public void run() {
    SecondClass[] secObj= new SecondClass[numberThreads];
    //start all
    for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
        secObj[i] = new SecondClass();
        secObj[i].start();
    }
    try {
        //wait
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Interrupt all
    for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
        secObj[i].interrupt();
    }
    System.out.println("MyClass is finished");
}
}
```

Outputs:

```
interrupted
interrupted
finished
finished
interrupted
finished
interrupted
finished
interrupted
finished
MyClass is finished
interrupted
finished
Main thread is finished
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. So except that time issue (if it is too short some other threads are not executed) this is correct to run and stop them all "simultaneously" after some given time? "par" was in my case numberThreads, I just forgot to change it here